# Generate pdf-file in php

Tags: php, arrays, pdf

I want to create a pdf file, but I always get this error:

> pdf file is damaged

The problem seems to be the line with `$spalten`, because if I add one more, I get the error.

For example:

```
$spalten = array('name', 'matrikelnummer', 'note');
```

otherwise this functions very well:

```
$spalten = array('name', 'note');
```

---

```
case 'pruefungsamt':
    $spalten = array('name', 'matrikelnummer');
    while (list($k, $fach) = each($global_fachrichtungen));
    { 
        if (!is_numeric($k))
        {
            $studenten = student_alleLesenFilter($dbh, $parameter['klausurid'], "NOT (versuch = 1 AND note > 4) AND NOT (fachrichtung='Schülerstudent')", 'sortname');

            if ($studenten)

                if (!pdf_erzeugeListe($pdf, $studenten, $spalten, true, $fach['name']))
                {
                    $error = true;
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
    if (!$error)
        pdf_send($pdf, 'pruefungsamtliste.pdf');
    else
        $smarty->assign('meldung', 'Fehler beim erstellen der Prüfungsamtliste');
    break;
```

And `var_dump($studenten)` delivers:

```
array(127) {
    [0]=> array(20) {
        ["id"]=> int(90) 
        ["matrikelnummer"]=>   Fili"
        ["fachrichtung"]=> string(10) "Informatik"
        ["punktesumme"]=> string(2)
```

I do not know where the mistake is. Is it because `$global_fachrichtungen` is

```
$global_fachrichtungen = array('Informatik' => array('name' => 'INFO'),
                               'Mathematik' => array('name' => 'MATH'),
                               .....
```

Her is the function `pdf_erzeugenListe`:

```
function pdf_erzeugeListe(&$pdf, $studenten, $spalten, $seitenzahlen = false, $ueberschrift = '')
{
    $spaltenname = array('name' => 'Name', 
                           'matrikelnummer' => 'Mat.-nr.', 
                           'note' => 'Note', 
//                         'punkte' => 'Pkte I', 
                           'punktesumme' => 'Punkte', 
                           'versuch' => 'Versuch',  
                           'semester' => 'Sem.', 
                           'nummer' => 'Nr.',
                           'fachrichtung' => 'Fachrichtung'
                         );


    $pad = 3;
    $hoehe = 6;
    $a4_hoehe = 297.30;
    $a4_breite = 200.22;
    $offset_top = 20;
    $offset_right = 20;

    $pdf->setFont('Arial','B', 10);

    $header = array();
    $widths = array();

    //Breite der Namens-Spalte feststellen:
    $maxbreite = $pdf->getStringWidth('Name');
    foreach($studenten as $s)
        $maxbreite = max($maxbreite, $pdf->getStringWidth($s['vorname'].' '.$s['name']));

    while (list($k, $s) = each($spalten))
    {
        $u = $spaltenname[$s];
        //  var_dump($u);
        //  die();

        $header[$k] = $u; //array_push($header, $u);

        if($s != 'name')
            $widths[$k] = $pdf->getStringWidth($u) + $pad; //array_push($widths, $pdf->getStringWidth($u) + $pad);
        else
            $widths[$k] = $maxbreite + $pad; //array_push($widths, $maxbreite + $pad);

    }
    $summe = 0;
    foreach($widths as $w)
        $summe += $w;
    if($summe > $a4_breite - 2 * $offset_right)
    {
        if($summe > $a4_breite)
            return false;
        else
            $offset_right = ($a4_breite - $summe) / 2;
    }

    $pdf->setMargins($offset_right, $offset_top);
    $zeilen_max = floor(($a4_hoehe - 2 * $offset_top) / $hoehe) - 3;
```

Are the values are right for the pdf?

Comment: Please try to create a minimal verifiable complete example. Nobody knows what these functions do `student_alleLesenFilter`, `pdf_erzeugeListe`.. Furthermore, did you look at the pdf file? What is wrong with it? Are there any errors on the webserver?

Comment: i think the mistake is in the pdf_erzeugeListe, is there mistake?